# Can not source a bash-script but can execute it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, shell-script

I am setting the testing environment for the travis-ci site using ubuntu.
The test commands are encapsulated in `/home/travis/test_build.sh` file, where I try to call a script which sets the environmental variables:`. ./checkout.sh` [like explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16011496/3152072)

During the execution of `checkout.sh` the variables are set correctly, but when the script finishes its executions I see that they are set back to empty (in `/home/travis/test_build.sh` where I actually need them).

How do I source the script properly in this case? Are there any settings I have to check to enable the soursing?

Short example of  `/home/travis/test_build.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what is 0: $0"
set -x
. ./checkout.sh
echo "COMP_ARCH=$COMP_ARCH"
echo "FRAME_BASE=$FRAME_BASE"
```

Short example of  `checkout.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what is 0: $0"
set -e
export COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
eval `scramv1 runtime -sh` # link scramv1 is set to some other script which is not mine, starts with `#!/bin/sh` and which is supposed to set some additional variables as FRAME_BASE
echo "COMP_ARCH=$COMP_ARCH"
echo "FRAME_BASE=$FRAME_BASE"
```

The output after execution of `/home/travis/test_build.sh` would be then:

```
what is 0: /home/travis/test_build.sh
what is 0: /home/travis/test_build.sh
COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
FRAME_BASE=/home/1234/wer/base
COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
FRAME_BASE=
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski , I do `source checkout.sh`. Since I am able to do ./checkout.sh I can be sure I am at right directory and the file exists

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, what I am actually doing I am running one single file like `/home/travis/test_build.sh` so I am interested in setting the system-variables in scope of this shell, inside of which I do first the `source checkout.sh`.
1) Both scripts have `#!/bin/bash` sheban
2) in both scripts I have echoed `$0` and got the same - the path to the `/home/travis/test_build.sh` (don't know if this is the right thing to have though)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I am sorry for the confusion, the error message is prompt whenever I do just `source checkout.sh` because it looks for this file only under known to `$PATH` directories but `. ./checkout.sh` performs without errors. In the second case the `checkout.sh` is executed - this I see via using `set +x`. And you are right about sourcing `checkout.sh` within `/home/travis/test_build.sh` - that is exactly what I am doing and - but after this step the env. variables are empty again...

Comment: *And you are right about sourcing checkout.sh within /home/travis/test_build.sh - that is exactly what I am doing and - but after this step the env. variables are empty again...* So the problem is not that you cannot source it but that the sourcing seems ineffective? In which case can you update your question the the code of oth scripts (perhaps restricted to the useful parts that still demonstrate the problem).

Comment: Variables being set to empty are unexpected. When a script is sourced, one and the same `bash` starts reading commands from *another* file, then goes back to original file and continues. I think something has to `unset` your variables somehow along the way. Are you the author of `checkout.sh`? Do you fully understand its code? Is this script so large or confidential that you cannot paste it here so we could analyze what it does?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I add the shorter version of the files to the question

Comment: I don't see that you are setting `$FRAME_BASE` anywhere. But my guess is that  `scramv1 runtime -sh` resets its value.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, I think it is set in `scramv1 runtime -sh` because `echo "FRAME_BASE=$FRAME_BASE"` right after it shows that the variable is not empty

Comment: So you're asking: How do I *export* a variable that is set in another script.

Comment: What is the output of `scramv1 runtime -sh` then?

Comment: You shouldn't `eval` scravm1 but `source` it... and pray. In fact, just source scravm1 in your main script and see if it changes the variables there. If it doesn't then if won't do it either if sourced from `checkout.sh` and you will have to find some other way to set these variables.

Comment: @xenoid Notice it's not `scramv1` what is evaluated; it's its output. I think if `scramv1` is designed to yield output to be evaluated then sourcing it will just echo something (with or without some side effects). And what about its arguments? I think you cannot respect them while sourcing, can you? But I don't know what exactly `scramv1` is and if it is used right in this case.

Comment: So that should work if `scramv1 runtime -sh` prints `export FRAME_BASE=Something`. Is it the case? And the args are passed OK. Easy enough to create a mock `scramv1` that prints what is required and check that the whole things works...   Note also how far we are now from **Can not source a bash-script but can execute it**

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79084/39076):

Use **`set -a`** before calling the code that defines the variable.

In your case, right after `set -e` you can add `set -a`.